# php - splitting a string with HTML by the first instance of a table cell

Tags: explode, preg-split

I am checking on HTML content on my page, and I've got the split down to have the variable left with this content:

```
  ">
                 <td>Oklahoma City</td>
              <td>Oklahoma</td>
     <td>OK</td>
     <td>405</td>
     <td>CST</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="
```

Those are dynamic pages I'm checking, so the data will always be different, but the layout the same...

How can I get the value out of the second `<td>` if that html is in 1 variable(string)?

It was a full page, I've used explode twice to remove everything above a div field and everything below the last dive field id... so it has some open html tags left because I did not know how to get rid of that along the way to be left with just this:

```
                 <td>Oklahoma City</td>
              <td>Oklahoma</td>
     <td>OK</td>
     <td>405</td>
     <td>CST</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Can you tell me how to get that out? I just need the second one because it is the county and that is what I'm checking on...

Comment: I was going to split by:
    '</td>' twice, then by '<td>' once, that should leave me with "Oklahoma" remaining...

Comment: use DOMDocument and DOMXPath, It isn't a job for `preg_split`

Comment: Never heard of DOMDocument or DOMXPath, what are they and where do I learn about them?